# Why does hibernate call an update when is call a get?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entity ,

the parent entity

```
Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Parent {

  @Column(name = "uuid")
  private UUID uuid;

  @Column(name = "type")
  private String type;

  @Column(name = "gateway")
  private String gateway;


  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "example")
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  private List<Child> childs;
  
...
other paramerters

}
```

and my child entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "unit")
    private String unit;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "example")
    private Parent parent;

...
other paramerters
}
```

so when i call the Get method which is under `@Transactional` it always execute a update operation?? why is that ? and how can i prevent that?

the get method

```
public class PublicImp implements CRUD {

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    @Override
    public Parent getParent(UUID uuid) {
List<Parent> parents = repository.findByUUID(uuid);
return parents.get(0);

    }
}
```

this is from the log

```
    update
        child 
    set
        unit=? 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        child 
    set
        unit=? 
    where
        id=?

2020-11-26 | 20:16:16.592 | http-nio-9797-exec-1 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder | binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [kWh]
2020-11-26 | 20:16:16.592 | http-nio-9797-exec-1 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder | binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [2493]
```

**EDIT :**
my repository

```
public interface DeviceInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent,String> {
  List<Parent> findByUUID(UUID uuid);

}
```

Comment: show your repository class

Comment: post  how have you implemented getParent(UUID) method and repository class too?

Comment: It updates the unit field, which means that you're probably calling `setUnit` on one the children`

Comment: updated , sorry for the delay

Comment: @coladict that's the point i'm not calling anything

Comment: share the implementation of `findByUUID`

Comment: @GovindaSakhare it's a JPA Repository it doesn't have a implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it , the issue was that i was using a `UserType` i.e is user implementation of Postgres datatype for json storage and retrival , the issue was the `equals(Object x , Object y)` was giving `false` as described by @Christian

> Usually this happens when an entity that is part of the persistence context is considered dirty and the query you are using touches the tables of these dirty entities.

so jpa thought it was dirty as equals always returned false , after fixing the equals function the code worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when an entity that is part of the persistence context is considered dirty and the query you are using touches the tables of these dirty entities. In order for such queries to return correct results, Hibernate must first flush the dirty state to the database.

Comment: I don't know how your real entities look like, but maybe using `entityManager.clear()` after the `find` might help here.

Comment: but i have posted my entities , and  i don't have an entity manger , spring boot takes care of presistence and other Transaction related issue

Comment: By default, Spring Data uses a feature called open session in view, which IMO is an anti-pattern. This causes the same entity manager to retain for your whole request, so to say what is going on, I'd need to see the other code as well. I guess you loaded an entity before and altered it? Now that you run this transactional method Hibernate flushes these changes automatically before committing.

Comment: i'm not able to recreate the same scenario seperatly for you to look at but when i looked it deeper it seems when i try to convert the entity to some thing else (which is simple getter and setter) i get this issue